# Lua - io.open() only up to 2 GB?

Tags: windows, file-io, lua

I am using a Lua script to determine the file size:

```
local filesize=0
local filePath = "somepath.bin"
local file,msg = io.open(filePath, "r")
if file then
    filesize=file:seek("end")
    file:close()
    filePresent = true
end
```

However, this only seem to work for files up to 2GB. For larger files `filesize` is always `nil`. Is there any limitation on `io.open`? And if so, how could I work around this?

Running Lua 5.1.4 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit

Comment: Btw., you should open binary files using `"rb"` instead of `"r"`.

Comment: Is upgrading to Lua 5.2 a possibility?

Comment: As the lua is acutally embedded I don't think that I could easily upgrade :( Whould 5.2 solve the issue?

Comment: Lua 5.2 would solve the issue, yes.

Comment: Hm, I just tried it with lua 5.2 and now I get -1 for the file size of files larger then 2gb?!

Comment: Strange, because under Windows you should get the 64-bit versions. See the definitions just before http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/liolib.c.html#l_fseek. Unless your compiler doesn't support this.

Comment: @lhf: If the compiler didn't support the 64-bit versions, the return value would still be `nil`. [Apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx#returnValueToggle) `_ftelli64` returns `-1L` on error -- my guess is that the OP is still using `"r"` when opening the file but it could well be something else entirely ...

Comment: No, I switched to "rb"

Comment: Are you compiling with MinGW by any chance? If so, the 64 bit functions will not be used. You can try adding the three necessary macros (linked to by lhf above) to the end of `luaconf.h` yourself -- if you get errors about `_fseeki64`/`_ftelli64` not being in `msvcrt.dll`, change the definition of `l_fseek` to `(_lseeki64(_fileno(f),o,w)<0?-1:0)` and `l_ftell` to `_telli64(_fileno(f))`. You will also have to include `<io.h>` in this case.

Comment: I acutally just used the precompiled binaires for Windows x64 (http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html) if that answers your question?!

Comment: Yes, those are compiled using MinGW 4, and as a consequence don't use the 64 bit functions for seeking. Either you compile Lua yourself, or you look for an external library for detecting file sizes ...

Comment: @lhf: You were right before: The `fseek`/`ftell` functions in MinGW behave differently than the MSVC ones. They don't fail at the `fseek` (which caused the `nil` return value earlier), but later at the `ftell` call.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not in `io.open`, but `file:seek`. You can check the error like this:

```
filesize, err = file:seek("end")
if not filesize then
    print(err)
end
```

The error message is probably `Invalid argument`. That's because for files larger than 2GB, its size is over what 32-bit `long` can hold, which causes the C function `fseek` fail to work.

In POSIX systems, Lua uses `fseeko` which takes the size of `off_t` instead of `long` in `fseek`. In Windows, there's a `_fseeki64` which I guess does similar job. If these are not available, `fseek` is used, and it would cause the problem.

---

The relevant source is [`liolib.c`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/liolib.c.html#f_seek)(Lua 5.2). As @lhf points out, in Lua 5.1, `fseek` is always used ([source](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/liolib.c.html#f_seek)). Upgrading to Lua 5.2 could possibly solve the problem.

Comment: But you still can read/write data larger then 2G. I read 9G file on Win2k3 (x32). You only can not do `seek`

Comment: Unfortunately, Lua 5.1 uses `fseek` only and does not try to use `fseeko`.

Comment: yes, right, I get the invalid argument.
So the only option is to use another library?!

Comment: @silent Upgrading to Lua 5.2 could possibly solve it, but I saw you already commented that it doesn't on your machine. Did you check the error message this time?

Comment: As I wrote above I dont get an error now but -1 as a result

Answer (score 3):

Internally, Lua uses the ISO C function `long int ftell(FILE *stream);` to determine the return value for `file:seek()`. A `long int` is always 32 bits on Windows, so you are out of luck here. If you can, you should use some external library to detect the file size -- I recommend [luafilesystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/).

Answer (score 0):

On old Lua versions (where `file:seek()` is limited to 2Gb) you can ask `cmd.exe` to get file size:

```
function filesize(filename)
   -- returns file size (or nil if the file doesn't exist or unable to open)
   local command = 'cmd /d/c for %f in ("'..filename..'") do @echo(%~zf'
   return tonumber(io.popen(command):read'*a')
end

print(filesize[[C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe]])
         --> 73728
print(filesize[[E:\City.of.the.Living.Dead.1980.720p.BluRay.x264.Skazhutin.mkv]])
         --> 8505168882
```